# прокрутка страница (по якорям/секциям)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullpage

Есть JS-библиотека для плавной прокрутки от секции к секции (Пример: https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#page1). Как реализовать ту же самую прокрутку, только без `fullpage.js`?

P.S. НЕ КНОПКА!

Answer (score 0):

плавный переход по якорям.

```
$(".anchor").on("click", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var id  = $(this).attr('href');
            $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: $(id).offset().top}, 700);
        });
```

Comment: Это код для кнопки?

Comment: @Antonio112009 делаешь ссылку(в `href='#blabla'`), для данной ссылки устанавливаешь класс `.anchor`, после создаешь блок с `id='blabla'`. и все будет работать=)

Comment: Короче, для кнопки. Увы, это не то, что надо. Проверь пример того, что я скинул

Comment: окей. делаете блоки высотой в `100vh`. После в js ловите событие на прокрутку колесиком вверх или вниз, после поднимаете скролл вверх или вниз.